# Bazinga Hateoas: Embed Array Collection

Tags: symfony, hateoas

I have an entity in my Symfony2 project called Department which has a OneToMany relationship with an entity User. I am trying to embed an array collection of users via the Bazinga Hateoas bundle.

If I embed a single user everything works fine. In this example, I am embedding a single instance of an entity.

```
  @Hateoas\Relation(
    "user",
    href = "expr('/api/staff/' ~ object.getUser().getId())",
    embedded = "expr(object.getUser())",
    exclusion = @Hateoas\Exclusion(excludeIf = "expr(object.getUser() === null)")
  )  //works
```

But if I try this with an array collection this does not work.

Comment: Any news about this? Did you figured it out?

Answer (score 0):

This solution could work for you

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;
use Hateoas\Configuration\Annotation as Hateoas;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

 /**
 * @JMS\ExclusionPolicy("all")
 * @Hateoas\Relation(
 *     "self",
 *     href = @Hateoas\Route(
 *         "get_department",
 *         parameters = { "id" = "expr(object.getId())" }
 *     )
 * ) 
 * @Hateoas\Relation(
 *     "users",
 *     href = @Hateoas\Route(
 *         "get_user",
 *         parameters = { "id" = "expr(object.getId())" }
 *     ),
 *     embedded = @Hateoas\Embedded(
 *         "expr(object.getUsers())",
 *          exclusion = @Hateoas\Exclusion(
 *              excludeIf = "expr(object.getUsers().isEmpty() === true)",
 *              groups={"users"},
 *              maxDepth = 1
 *          )
 *     ),
 *     exclusion = @Hateoas\Exclusion(
 *          excludeIf = "expr(object.getUsers().isEmpty() === true)",
 *          groups={"users"},
 *          maxDepth = 1
 *      )
 * )
 */
 class Department
 {

     /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="department")
     * @JMS\MaxDepth(1)
     */
    protected $users;


    /**
     * Add user
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $user
     *
     * @return Department
     */
    public function addUser(\AppBundle\Entity\User $user)
    {
        $this->users[] = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove user
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $user
     */
    public function removeUser(\AppBundle\Entity\User $user)
    {
        $this->users->removeElement($user);
    }

    /**
     * Get users
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }   
 }
```